# How would `pseudo_encrypt(int)` primary keys affect performance in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, random

I was planning to use UUIDv4 for the primary key but it's way too long to share as part of URL. I was thinking of using [`pseudo_encrypt(int)`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt) as primary key. How would that affect lookup performance for a table with couple billion rows? It's a schema divided multi-tenant system by the way.

Also, if it's fine to use this, how can I lock [`bounded_pseudo_encrypt(int, int)`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt_constrained_to_an_arbitrary_range) between 1000000000 - 9999999999? I understand the calculations there but I don't understand the significance of the numbers used.

Comment: Tables can have more than one Key. I recommend separating an “external mapping” (CK/AK or even perhaps another table) from a PK unless there is a NK that can be (‘naturally’) exposed.

Comment: This AK/CK/mapping is used externally (such as a “secret” or “friendly” link) - the PK is used in the application domain.

Comment: As far as “performance”: probably not noticeable/relevant in most use-case. However, it may cause more insert fragmentation which does require additional overhead and maintenance.

Comment: Well, there goes my billion dollar idea 
So, I would have to build kind of a URL shortner service to get around this.

Comment: That still creates another similar issue. I think I'll go with a secondary column.

Comment: It’s not necessarily bad - and reduces the ability for a generic “simple” iteration of IDs. It does *not* actually add security as the sequence can also be generated by an adversary using the same algorithm. Comments above are merely experience suggestions.

Comment: You're right. I didn't really think like that. It doesn't add much of a security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the second part. 9999999999 is a BigInt. So instead I went ahead with max unsigned int value 2147483647.

Modified the function to take a MIN parameter and compare the MIN parameter to the value on exiting loop where they compared MAX.

```
CREATE FUNCTION bounded_pseudo_encrypt(VALUE int, MIN int, MAX int) returns int AS $$
BEGIN
  LOOP
    VALUE := pseudo_encrypt_24(VALUE);
    EXIT WHEN VALUE >= MIN AND VALUE <= MAX;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN VALUE;
END
```

This creates a problem. The values are not distinct anymore.